# Rails pass extra data from controller action to serializer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, active-model-serializers

I need to pass extra data from the show action in the controller to the serializer on rendere method.

I have a render like this:

```
render json: test, serializer: TestSerializer
```

The json that is returned is something like this:

```
{
  "test": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Name",
    "surname": "Surname",
  }
}
```

I need to pass extra data to this serializer in order to have a json like this:

```
render json: test, serializer: TestSerializer, extradata: extradata

{
  "test": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Name",
    "surname": "Surname",
    "extradata": {
      "first": 1,
      "second": 12
    }
  }
}
```

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you can merge extra data to `test` before rendering it. May be `test.merge!(extradata: extradata)` before line `render json: test, serializer: TestSerializer`

Comment: @Abhi thank you very much.

Comment: Right now I'm not in a position to test this, so if you get your code working, please post it as answer and accept it, so that it helps others.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this to resolve my problem very quickly:

**Controller.rb before**

```
render json: test, serializer: TestSerializer
```

**Json before**

```
{
  "test": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Name",
    "surname": "Surname",
  }
}
```

**Controller.rb after**

```
extradata = "test text"
render json: test, serializer: TestSerializer, extradata: extradata
```

**Json after**

```
{
 "test": {
   "id": 1,
    "name": "Name",
    "surname": "Surname",
    "extradata": "test text"
   }
 }
```